# Group DataTable by multiple columns and concatenate strings with a limit

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `datatable` having columns as follows :

```
Agent   Country City
A       India   Delhi
B       India   Delhi
C       India   Delhi
D       India   Delhi
E       India   Delhi
AA      India   Mumbai
BB      India   Mumbai
CC      India   Mumbai
DD      India   Lucknow
EE      India   Lucknow
FF      India   Lucknow
GG      India   Lucknow
```

what i need is :

```
Agent       Country City
A,B,C       India   Delhi
D,E         India   Delhi
AA,BB,CC    India   Mumbai
DD,EE,FF    India   Lucknow
GG          India   Lucknow
```

i want to concat the Agent to a maximum limit of 3. I tried to use the following code :

```
var result = dt1.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => new { Country = x.Field<string>("Country"), 
                            City = x.Field<string>("City") })
        .Select(x => new 
           {
               Agent = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.Field<string>("Agent"))),
               Country = x.Key.Country,
               City = x.Key.City
           });
```

i am getting the following result

```
Agent            Country    City
A,B,C,D,E        India      Delhi
AA,BB,CC         India      Mumbai
DD,EE,FF,GG      India      Lucknow
```

Can you help me to find a way , so that i can set the limit of agent to 3 and then a new row to next 3 agents.

This is just a sample scenario. the real data have a lot of agents and i need to limit those to configurable limit.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am i asking a wrong question? why down voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, the trick is the `SelectMany` and the inner `GroupBy` on the integer division result:

```
var result = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { Country = x.Field<string>("Country"), City = x.Field<string>("City") })
    .SelectMany(group => group
        .Select((row, index) => new { Row = row, Index = index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Agents = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Row.Field<string>("Agent"))),
            group.Key.Country, group.Key.City
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks ... it is working as expected for my 3k+ records. I am curious about the performance for some lacs records. Will it take more time for some lacs records and limit will be approx 15000 agents?

Comment: @Devendra: of course it needs more time. But if you have a performance bottleneck you should use the database instead of loading all into memory

Comment: My database server is Mysql. So how can i achieve this with query?

Comment: @Devendra: sorry but i don't get you. The task was to do this with a `DataTable`, it has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: Yes, i asked with LINQ and your solution is working fine, but as you suggested me that i should use the database instead of loading into memory. So i am curious, how can i do it using query as my datatable is loaded from database table. Sorry but asking for your help again :)

Comment: @Devendra: i'm not a MySql expert but that's a different question so ask another one

Comment: Ok, Thanks for you help. I am marking your solution as my answer :)